# Python for * in * цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, for

В переменной `ItemsID` есть много разных ID, например таких:

```
23998415327
23998414914
23998412075
23998404571
23998402338
```

Также есть команда в центр, которой нужно подставить эти ID (я пометил куда). Приблизительно это должно выглядеть следующим образом:

```
sessionid=e8537cfd897ac9151a47fec9&appid=730&contextid=2&assetid=СЮДА НУЖНО ПОДСТАВИТЬ ID &amount=1&price=90
```

Задача должна по кругу крутиться N раз и постоянно менять ID на следующее. Как мне это сделать? Я понимаю что нужно использовать цикл `for * in *`, но никак не могу собрать всё как нужно. Помогите мне, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: `ItemsID` какого вида? Строка? Список? В общем случае подстановка делается через f-строки, например. `for ID in ItemsID:    print(f"sessionid=e8537cfd897ac9151a47fec9&appid=730&contextid=2&assetid={ID}&amount=1&price=90")`

Comment: Вид строка. Щас немного переделаю мой код и попробую твой способ, спасибо. Потом отпишу как

Comment: @GrAnd Всё в str. Я попробовал этот код и он берёт только 1 цифру подставляет, потом 2 и.т.д. Мне нужно чтобы эту строку в цифрами полностью а не по одной цифре.
Примерно должно выглядеть так:
sessionid=e8537cfd897ac9151a47fec9&appid=730&contextid=2&assetid=23998415327&amount=1&price=90
sessionid=e8537cfd897ac9151a47fec9&appid=730&contextid=2&assetid=23998414914&amount=1&price=90

Comment: Тогда используйте `for ID in ItemsID.split():`.

Comment: @GrAnd Теперь он всё верно пишет но вечно один и тот же ИД, первый ид

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой способ и самый оптимальный

```
n=число повторов
for _ in range(n): #Запускаем цикл повторов
  for id in ItemsId.splitlines(): #запускаем цикл прохода по элементам
     new_variable='aaaabbbbXXXccc'.replace('XXX',id) #заменяем ХХХ на текущий элемент
```

Так же есть варианты, не смотря на то что они рабочие, но всё же менее желательны с точки зрения модуля this. К примеру:

```
a=[1,2] исходный список
for it in a*3: #увеличиваем исходный список в три раза
   #replace
```

upd: здесь идёт переназначение системной функции id, что не критично, но всё же не желательно

Comment: Долго думал над 2 вариантом, не понимаю как он работает. 1 Вариант отлично сработал, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: второй вариант, суть увеличение исходного списка в нужное количество раз то есть ```a=[1,2]; b=a*3 #[1,2,1,2,1,2]```